# Rails 4 : stack level too deep when trying to access relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is one migration

```
class AddAssociationsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :associations do |t|

            # user_id : Reference to the user profile to whom the association belongs
            t.belongs_to :user, null: false
            # secret_token : Secret Token used to make API request on behalf of the user
            t.string :secret_token, null: false
            # access_token : Access Token used to make API request on behalf of the user
            t.string :access_token, null: false
            # public : Allows users to make their information public or keep it just to themselves
            t.boolean :public, default: true

            t.timestamps
        end

        add_index :associations, :user_id
    end
end
```

This the second migration

```
class AddUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|

            # uid ; Twitter user ID
            t.integer :twitter_id

            # name : Real name provided to Twitter
            t.string :name

            # screen_name : Username on Twitter
            t.string :screen_name

            # description : Self Description on Twitter
            t.text :description

            # location : Locatin provided by User to Twitter
            t.string :location

            # lang : Language used on Twitter
            t.string :lang

            # profile_img : URL to profile image
            t.string :profile_image_url

            # tweet_count : Amount of tweets posted
            t.integer :statuses_count

            # followers_count : Amount of follwers at the current moment
            t.integer :followers_count

            # friends_count : Amount of friends/following at the current moment
            t.integer :friends_count

            # listed_count : Amount of lists in which the user is a part of
            t.integer :listed_count

            # verified : Verified by Twitter to be the claimed person (Used mostly for celebraties)
            t.boolean :verified

            # created_at : date at which user joined Twitter
            t.date :created_at
        end

        add_index :users, :twitter_id
        add_index :users, :screen_name
    end
end
```

Then I have the following Models

```
class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:twitter]

    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :association
end
```

Whenever I run something like that:
    User.first.association

I get stack level too deep. Does anyone know where is the problem?

Full Trace:

```
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the `Association` is a bad model name (and `:association` is a bad association name...) try renaming it

Comment: I don't think you can write ` t.belongs_to :user, null: false` in a migration. Shouldn't it be `t.integer :user_id, null: false` ?

Comment: @Trip It does the same thing, it just another name [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: @UriAgassi You were right, `Association` is a bad name that created the stack level too deep issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a name conflict. When you declare `has_one :association`, rails looks for constant `Association`. You would expect it will point to you model `Association`. Unfortunatelly there already is a constant called `Association` within your User class and it is defined as `ActiveRecord::Associations::Association`.

In short, you need to rename your model - it cannot be named 'Association'

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the issue, I renamed my model into `Organization` and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think renaming the association should do the trick?

```
has_one :new_name, class_name: "association"
```